# Malfunctioning rectangle collision code

Tags: objective-c, collision-detection

I have the following code:

```
+(bool)Point:(CGPoint)point isInRectangle:(CGRect)rect
{
    int rectx1 = rect.origin.x;
    int recty1 = rect.origin.y;
    int rectx2 = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width;
    int recty2 = rect.origin.y + rect.size.width;
    int pointx = point.x;
    int pointy = point.y;
    return (pointx >= rectx1 && pointx <= rectx2) && (pointy >= recty1 && pointy <= recty2);
}
```

It's supposed to detect the collision between two rectangles, but I am not getting the correct value. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here:

```
int recty2 = rect.origin.y + rect.size.width;
```

you probably meant:

```
int recty2 = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height;
```

But, you should know there is already a C function CGRectContainsPoint (rect, point) that does what you want. So you don't have to write one unless you want to.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the built in geometry functions?

```
CGRect CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint pt);
CGRect CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2);
```

That's what they're there for. :) Docs for these and many other useful functions at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

One of these lines should be height not width.

> ```
> int rectx2 = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width;
> int recty2 = rect.origin.y + rect.size.width;
> ```